# RecyclerViews inside NestesScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I want to place two RecyclerViews inside a NestedScrollView where all items of each RecyclerView should be displayed:

```
Desired:                    Current:
---------------------       --------------------- 
Fixed Header content        Fixed Header content
---------------------       ---------------------
<NestedScrollView>          <NestedScrollView>
  EditText                    EditText 
  EditText                    EditText
  ...                         ...
  <RecyclerView>              <RecyclerView> (scrollable>
   Item 1                       Item 1
   Item 2                     </RecyclerView>
   ...                        <RecyclerView> (scrollable>
   Item N                       Item 2
  </RecyclerView>             </RecyclerView>
  <RecyclerView>              </NestedScrollView>
   Item 1                     --------------------
   Item 2
   ...
   Item M
  </RecyclerView>
</NestedScrollView>
----------------------
```

Currently, only the first item of each RecyclerView is displayed and you can scroll down to the other items within this limited space.

I have tried to set `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` with the effect that still only the first item of the RecyclerView is displayed, and the RecyclerView is not scrollable anymore.

This all is contained in a Fragment which is included in an Activity hosting a BottomNavigationView.

*Activity layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context=".gui.activity.MainActivity">

  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>-->


  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_color"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_main_activity" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*Fragment layout:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    ... fixed header content ...

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout 
              ...
            />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catHeader1"
                style="@style/Me.CatHeader"
                android:layout_below="@id/dummy1"
                android:text="@string/textCat1" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/catHeader1"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action1"
                style="@style/Me.AddText"
                android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView1"
                android:text="@string/action1"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/catHeader2"
                style="@style/Me.CatHeader"
                android:layout_below="@id/action1"
                android:text="@string/textCat2" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/catHeader2"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action2"
                style="@style/Me.AddText"
                android:layout_below="@id/recyclerView2"
                android:text="@string/action2"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Both RecyclerViews use a vertical LinearLayoutManager.

Using `match_parent` on the RecyclerViews height doesn't change anything.

AppCompat version: 25.1.0

What am I missing, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21080728. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the problem:**

The root layout for the items had `layout_height = match_parent`, setting it to `layout_height = ?listPreferredItemHeight` solved it all.

Comment: Why you are using 2 RecyclerView's?

Comment: Both RecyclerViews display very different content/items where it is easier to put it into two Adapters instead of handling it in one.

Comment: Its not a good practice to create separate RecyclerView or ListView whether  you have same data types or not.